# How to add awgn noise to a signal in Fourier domain for given SNR

Tags: signal-power

I want to know the equations required to add awgn noise to a signal in Fourier domain for different SNR values. I know the procedure in time domain but not able to do the same in  frequency domain for the signal $x(t) = e^{2 \pi j f t}$ .

Thank you

Comment: Does your signal $x(n)$ depend on $n$ ?

Comment: Can you please confirm if your exponent should involve the $n$ variable (rather than $t$)? Have you looked up [what does the white noise spectrum look like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise#White_noise)?

Comment: @AlexTP sorry it is x(t). I want to implement it in MATLAB.

Comment: Can you explain how your expected results differ from your actual results? Or accept the answer from Marcus below since it is perfectly valid?

Answer (score -1):

Since the Fourier transform (and its discrete version) is linear, there is literally no difference in the way you do this in time and frequency domain:

You observe the energy in your signal, set the Gaussian's variance according to the desired SNR, and add the noise. Not a single flop was given about in which domain you were that day!

Comment: Can u provide with an example in frequency domain

Comment: You said you've done it in frequency domain. So I propose you consider your own code an example.

Comment: The reason why I need it in frequency domain is , if im adding the awgn noise in time domain then due to fft gain my SNR changes in frequency domain. I want to achieve a 20db SNR in frequency domain.

Comment: I have not done it in frequency domain. I dono how to add noise to my frequency spectrum.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my side. You've done it in time domain. Do exactly the same in frequency domain. Your own code is your example.